# Can you run a Windows Application inside Linux without Third Party Software like WINE?

Tags: linux, operating-systems, window, wine, software-update

I want to install an application originally designed for Windows in Ubuntu, but I don't want to install other software, such as [WINE](https://www.winehq.org/), to be able to do it.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

Unless you write your own library to do it, the answer is simply No.

Executable files (.exe) are binaries compiled to run on a Windows system. Linux cannot interpret these files because (among MANY other reasons) it cannot support the calls to Win32 API. The point of WINE, and other such programs, is to take these calls meant for Windows and translate them into something Linux can understand.

Example

> Person A (Windows) - Speaks only English
>
> Person B (WINE) - Speaks English and Portuguese
>
> Person C (Linux) - Speak only Portuguese

Person A `Windows .exe` makes a call in English saying "Hey, read that file from the hard drive", Person B`WINE` translates that into Portuguese and makes the same call in Portuguese to Person C `Linux`.

Comment: Excellent analogy! Nice!

Answer (score -1):

The answer is **no!!!** This is because software made for Windows uses Windows APIs that only work on Windows.